# Decorate a block of text with a digraph box

Tags: vim

Is there a vim scrip to allow me to visually select a box, then put a box around it using digraphs?

For example, input:

```
Hello World
```

And the output after visual selection (and the calling the script)

```
┌─────────────┐
│ Hello world │
└─────────────┘
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting... I had to do a lot of those re-formatting, thus I wrote a script called "BlockIt", do exactly what you want I guess. And it can do more than that.

Check it out:

https://github.com/sk1418/blockit

Comment: The script is great! It seems to not be able to use digraphs for box drawing (doesn't compute the length correctly). Is there any easy way to make it do so?

Comment: yep, I wrote it only for ascii borders. you have to extend the length calculation part. There is no easy way to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Jensen has [a command-line utility named "Boxes"](https://boxes.thomasjensen.com/) that does what you're asking, and in a wide variety of ways. It [integrates well with vim](https://boxes.thomasjensen.com/editors-vim.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but [DrawIt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) (command \b) should do that.
Look at [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org) for other drawing scripts ([link to my search results](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=draw&script_type=utility&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visual block mode` for this purpose.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual mode.

Move arrows left, right, up and down to select your box. (If you wanted to interchange the ends, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. I mean, we usually select through the bottom right end. If you want to switch to top left corner and select topside, you can use this)

Now, after making the selection to fit your desired box size, you can fill it with a character like #,* or whatever you want.
Press `r#` to replace the entire box with a #. You can put any character after `r`.

Now, your box is full of characters.
You want to type something inside! You can enter replace mode by pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd> twice.
Then, start typing your text . press `Esc` once done.

Comment: I will edit the answer if you provide more info. If you want alternate way also, I will specify it